# Has IModelBinder signature changed in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am just following a MVC 5 book and it is creating a custom model binder for its shopping cart. 
What he has in the book is:

```
“public class CartModelBinder : IModelBinder {
        private const string sessionKey = "Cart";

        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
            ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {”

Excerpt From: Adam Freeman. “Pro ASP.NET MVC 5.” iBooks.
```

And when I started typing and created my class it automatically created this:

```
public class CartModelBinder: IModelBinder
    {
        private const string sessionKey = "Cart";
        public bool BindModel(ModelBindingExecutionContext modelBindingExecutionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
```

That one returns an objects and accepts different parameters than the one IDE created for me. So now what should we do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The book is referring to `System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder`; your implementation is using `System.Web.ModelBinding.IModelBinder`.

There are actually 3 different `IModelBinder` interfaces defined that you may encounter. The third definition is contained in System.Web.Http and is used for Web API.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24184559/453277) covers the *why*. In brief, they are different implementations for different purposes ( MVC, Web Forms, and Web API).

Comment: oh ReSharper! Stop choosing namespaces for me!

Comment: Yeah, I've gotten caught by this before. There are numerous types with multiple definitions (like attributes) that can be very confusing.